# How is it possile that a write statement affects a Fortran code?

Tags: fortran

I have written s subroutine for a commercial software which is compiled by Intel Fortran so that the code has been written in Fortran. the subroutine is compiled by itself without any problem, but when I link it to the main software I get some strange results.

The most interesting and surprising event is:

When I put a `write` statement in the subroutine I get different results than there is no `write` statement within it  and also by changing the place of this statement, the results are changed. I have never seen that the `write` statement can affect the results. It would be really appreciated if someone give me an idea?

Comment: This is nearly a Fortran FAQ.  Lots of Qs and As here on SO, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331608/fortran-runtime-error-fixed-by-writing-output

Comment: Asked many times here. Compile with `gfortran -fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace` or `ifort -check -warn -g traceback` or equivalent and see (and report your findings here).

Answer (score 3):

This is typical undefined behaviour, reflecting a bug somewhere else. This can be whatever, like a corrupted stack, out of bounds memory accesses, etc...

Time to compile with debug options, bound checking, etc, and to give the debugger a try.

Assuming you are on Linux, try adding "-g -O0 -check all" to your compiler command line options. This could report interesting informations at run time.

Also try to run your code with gdb and examine the call stack at crash time with `bt`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. So, is it possible to tell me a little bit more about the debug otions or boun checking procedure or at least introduce me a good refrence please? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: Oops, Intel, right? Then try "-g -O0 -check all" for a stater.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is Intel. Sorry, but I dont get your point. what is the meaning of "-g -O0 -check all". I know it would be rediciulus to you, but I dont know about this. Thanks

Comment: I am working on Windows 8  and also 7. Not linux. This command could be applied also on Windows?

Comment: compiler options would become `/debug:full /check /traceback` I guess, but I don't have Windows to check

Comment: On windows, enter `ifort /?` to see a list of all compiler options.  You can also redirect this to a text file with `ifort /? > help.txt` if you don't like paging through the help at the command line.