# Including/omitting write statement changes code output in Fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am facing a difficult to debug problem in this Fortran 90 code - keeping or commenting out `write(*,*)` statements is changing the output of the code! Here are the details and the code (cannot minimize more as that may not cause the same bug):

Os: Ubuntu 16.04
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

FORTRAN90 code name: gillsp_notworking.f90
compiling with: gfortran -ffree-line-length-none gillsp_notworking.f90

These are the two problematic lines (marked as !***** error write ****):
W1: write statement at line number 421
W2: write statement at line number 422

The code:

```
    program code

    implicit none

    real*8, parameter :: time=3600.d0, t0=0.d0
    real*8, parameter :: er=1.d-6
    real*8, parameter :: vton=600.d0
    real*8, parameter :: dl=1.d0/370.d0

    real*8,parameter :: kp1be = 11.6d0/vton, km1be = 1.4d0
    real*8,parameter :: kp2be = 3.4d0/vton, km2be = 0.2d0
    real*8,parameter :: kp3be = 2.9d0/vton, km3be = 5.4d0


    real*8,parameter :: kp1pe = 0.d0/vton, km1pe = 0.d0
    real*8,parameter :: kp2pe = 0.d0/vton, km2pe = 0.d0
    real*8,parameter :: kp3pe = 0.d0/vton, km3pe = 0.d0  

    real*8,parameter :: kpdom = 16.d-5/vton
    real*8,parameter :: kpcf = 13.d0/vton, kmcf = 0.7d0
    real*8,parameter :: kmbcf = 4.4, kmpcf = 0.d0
    real*8,parameter :: ktd = 0.003d0
    real*8,parameter :: ktdpi = 0.3d0
    real*8,parameter :: ksever = 0.01d0

    real*8,parameter :: kcp0=12.8d0/vton, kcm0=2.d-4
    real*8,parameter :: kcp1=0.3d0/vton, kcm1=6.d-3 

    real*8,parameter :: alpha = 20.d0

    real*8,parameter :: rho = 0.3d0 
    real*8,parameter :: rhocf = 0.8d0
    real*8,parameter :: rhocp = 0.d0
    real*8,parameter :: V = 1.d0


    integer, parameter :: Nmin=100,Npos=nint(60.d0/dl)
    integer, parameter :: N=nint(rho*vton*V)
    integer, parameter :: Ncf=nint(rhocf*vton*V)
    integer, parameter :: Ncp=nint(rhocp*vton*V/1000.d0)
    integer, parameter :: nstep=300
    integer, parameter :: ndmax=3000

    integer, parameter :: minsevL=10

    integer, parameter :: plotmovie=1
    
    real*8, parameter :: delt=time/nstep

    real*8 :: t,r1,r2,pl,ph

    real*8 :: tau
    real*8 :: beta1,beta2,beta3,beta4,beta5,beta6,beta7,beta8,beta_sev
    real*8 :: beta_cp,beta_cm
    real*8 :: beta_sum
    real*8 :: alpha0
    real*8 :: rsev1,rsev2
    real*8 :: pifactr

    integer :: m, m1(-Nmin:Npos), m10(-Nmin:Npos)
    integer :: mcf, domL(1:ndmax),domR(1:ndmax), ndom,cofcount,domLen
    integer :: cap
    integer :: domL0(1:ndmax),domR0(1:ndmax),drcount,domrem(1:ndmax)
    integer :: pesever(1:10),besever(1:10),besvcount,pesvcount, sevindex, dumind

    integer :: i,j,k,nk
    integer :: l1(-Nmin:Npos)
    integer :: l1bind, l1pind, l1bind0, l1pind0
    integer :: gatp1, gadppi1, gadp1, glcf1, gzero
    integer :: l1sum

    integer :: k1,k2, dgcount, dscount, nmerge, domflag
    integer :: nfile

    integer :: dumdl
    integer :: Bstate
    integer :: nPicof

    integer :: seed(12)

    character*80::fname, Rid

    write(*,*) 'Array size=', -Nmin, Npos

!------------------------------------------------------

    seed= 9878771

        CALL RANDOM_SEED (PUT=seed)

!------------------------------------------------------

    t=0
    nk=0
    nfile=0

!----------- initialisation -----------

    l1=0
    m1=0
    l1bind=0
    l1pind=-1
    
    m=N 
    cap=Ncp

    Bstate = 1
    pifactr = 1.d0

    ndom=0
    cofcount=0
    domL=0
    domR=0
    nPicof=0
    mcf=Ncf-sum(domR-domL)-ndom

!********************************************************************
!********************************************************************
!------------------- time loop ------------------------

    tloop: do while (t.le.time)

!----------------- counting G-atp, G-adp, G-cofilin in filament --------------

    gzero=count(m1<er)
    gatp1=count(m1<1+er) - gzero
    gadppi1=count(m1<2+er) - (gatp1+gzero)
    gadp1=count(m1<3+er) - (gatp1+gzero+gadppi1)
    glcf1=count(m1>3+er)

!----------------- current length ---------------------

    l1sum = sum(l1)

!------------------ propensity sum ---------------------

!---- store monomer states, domain info etc -----

    m10 = m1
    l1bind0=l1bind
    l1pind0=l1pind
    domL0=domL
    domR0=domR

!------------------- capping reaction ------------------

    if (m10(l1bind-1).eq.4) then

    if(Bstate.eq.1)then
    beta_cp = kcp1*cap/V
    beta_cm = 0.d0
    elseif (Bstate.eq.2) then
    beta_cp = 0.d0
    beta_cm = kcm1
    endif

    else

    if(Bstate.eq.1)then
    beta_cp = kcp0*cap/V
    beta_cm = 0.d0
    elseif (Bstate.eq.2) then
    beta_cp = 0.d0
    beta_cm = kcm0
    endif

    endif

!-------------------- barbed end -----------------------

    if(Bstate.eq.1)then     ! Barbed-end state if

    if(m10(l1bind-1).eq.1)then
    beta1 = km1be
    beta2 = kp1be*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1bind-1).eq.2) then
    beta1 = km2be
    beta2 = kp2be*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1bind-1).eq.3) then
    beta1 = km3be
    beta2 = kp3be*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1bind-1).eq.4) then
    beta1 = kmbcf
    beta2 = 0.d0
    endif

    elseif (Bstate.eq.2) then

    beta1 = 0.d0
    beta2 = 0.d0

    endif

    !----- the first monomer incorporation------!
    if(t.lt.30)then
    if(m10(l1bind-1).eq.0)then
    beta2 = kp1be*(m/V)
    endif
    endif


!-------------------- pointed end -----------------------
    
    if(m10(l1pind+1).eq.1) then
    beta3 = km1pe
    beta4=kp1pe*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1pind+1).eq.2) then
    beta3 = km2pe
    beta4=kp2pe*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1pind+1).eq.3) then
    beta3 = km3pe
    beta4 = kp3pe*(m/V)
    elseif (m10(l1pind+1).eq.4) then
    beta3 = kmpcf
    beta4 = 0.d0
    endif


!------------------- bulk reactions ---------------------

!------------------ cofilin reactions ------------------
    if(ndom.gt.0)then
    nmerge=0
    do k1=1,ndom
    do k2=1,ndom
    if(domL(k1)-1.eq.domR(k2)) nmerge=nmerge+1
    enddo
    enddo
    endif

!---------------- Pi-cofilin interface ------------------

    nPicof=0
    do k1=l1pind0,l1bind0-1
    if(abs(m10(k1)-m10(k1+1)).eq.2.and.m10(k1)+m10(k1+1).eq.6)then
    nPicof=nPicof+1
    endif
    enddo


        !------------------- bulk reactions ---------------------

    beta5 = ktdpi*gatp1 + ktd*(gadppi1-nPicof) + alpha*ktd*nPicof

    beta6 = kpdom*(mcf/V)*max(0.d0,(gadp1-2.d0*ndom-2.d0*nmerge))

    !----- count domain growth probability -----
    if(ndom.gt.0)then
    dgcount=0
    dscount=0
    do k=1,ndom

    dumdl=domR(k)-domL(k)-1 

    if(m10(domL(k)).eq.3) dgcount=dgcount+1
    if(m10(domR(k)).eq.3) dgcount=dgcount+1

    if(m10(domL(k)).le.3.and.dumdl.gt.2) dscount=dscount+1
    if(m10(domR(k)).le.3.and.dumdl.gt.2) dscount=dscount+1
    enddo
    else
    dgcount=0
    dscount=0
    endif

    beta7 = kpcf*(mcf/V)*dgcount    

    beta8 = kmcf*dscount    

    !----- severing probability -----
    if(ndom.gt.0)then
    besvcount=0
    pesvcount=0
    besever=-1
    pesever=-1
    do k=1,ndom
    domLen = domR(k)-domL(k)-1
    if (domLen.ge.minsevL) then 
    if(m10(domL(k)).lt.4.and.m10(domL(k)).gt.0) then
    pesvcount=pesvcount+1
    pesever(pesvcount)=domL(k)
    endif
    if(m10(domR(k)).lt.4.and.m10(domR(k)).gt.0) then
    besvcount=besvcount+1
    besever(besvcount)=domR(k)
    endif
    else        !------ domain length condition
    pesvcount=0
    besvcount=0
    endif       !------ domain length condition
    enddo
    else
    pesvcount=0
    besvcount=0
    endif

    beta_sev = ksever*(besvcount+pesvcount)     
    
    beta_sum = beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta5+beta6+beta7 &
                   +beta8+beta_sev+beta_cp+beta_cm

    alpha0 = beta_sum

!----------------- next reaction time: tau --------------

    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r1)
    if(r1.lt.1.d-8)then     
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r1)
    endif

    tau = (1.d0/alpha0)*log(1.d0/r1)

!----------------------- all reactions ------------------------

    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r2)


!---------------- growth and decay ------------------

!---------------- filament 1 ----------------
!---------------- barbed end ----------------
    pl=0.d0
    ph=beta1/alpha0
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph.and.l1sum.gt.er) then     
    if (m1(l1bind-1).eq.4) then
!   mcf = mcf+1 Pool conc. remains same
    do k=1,ndom
    if(domR(k).eq.l1bind) domR(k)=domR(k)-1
    enddo
    endif
    l1bind = l1bind - 1
    l1(l1bind) = 0
    m1(l1bind) = 0
!   m = m+1     Pool conc. remains same
    Rid="BE-"
    endif

    pl=beta1/alpha0
    ph=(beta1+beta2)/alpha0
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then         
    m1(l1bind) = 1
    l1(l1bind) = 1
    l1bind = l1bind + 1
!   m = m-1     Pool conc. remains same
    Rid="BE+"
    endif

!---------------- pointed end ---------------

    pl=(beta1+beta2)/alpha0
    ph=(beta1+beta2+beta3)/alpha0
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph.and.l1sum.gt.er) then     
    if (m1(l1pind+1).eq.4) then
!   mcf = mcf+1 Pool conc. remains same
    do k=1,ndom
    if(domL(k).eq.l1pind) domL(k)=domL(k)+1
    enddo
    endif
    l1pind = l1pind + 1
    l1(l1pind) = 0
    m1(l1pind) = 0
!   m = m+1     Pool conc. remains same
    Rid="PE-"
    endif

    pl=(beta1+beta2+beta3)/alpha0
    ph=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4)/alpha0
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then             
    m1(l1pind) = 1
    l1(l1pind) = 1
    l1pind = l1pind - 1
!   m = m-1     Pool conc. remains same
    Rid="PE+"
    endif

!---------- severing of filament -------------

    pl=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4)/alpha0
    ph=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta_sev)/alpha0
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then         
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rsev1)
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rsev2)
    if(rsev1.le.0.2d0.and.besvcount.gt.0)then       
    dumind = 1 + nint(rsev2*(besvcount-1))          
    sevindex = besever(dumind)          
    else

    if (pesvcount.gt.0) then                            
    dumind = 1 + nint(rsev2*(pesvcount-1))      
    sevindex = pesever(dumind)
    else
    dumind = 1 + nint(rsev2*(besvcount-1))      
    sevindex = besever(dumind)
    endif

    endif           


    l1bind=sevindex     ! keep olp pointed end
    Bstate=1        ! set new barbed end free
!   m=m+(l1bind0-sevindex)  Pool conc. remains same
    m1(sevindex:l1bind0)=0
    l1(sevindex:l1bind0)=0

    drcount=0
    domrem=0
    do j=sevindex,l1bind0               ! j-loop
!   if(m10(j).eq.4) then        Pool conc. remains same
!   mcf=mcf+1
!   endif
    do k=1,ndom
    if(domL(k).eq.j)then
    drcount=drcount+1
    domrem(drcount)=j
    domL(k)=0
    domR(k)=0
    endif
    enddo
    enddo       ! j-loop
    Rid="SEVER"
!   write(*,*)'sever', m10(sevindex-1) ,sevindex, l1bind0, besvcount, pesvcount !***** error write ****
!   write(*,*)'sever', m10(sevindex-1)                      !***** error write ****
    endif           ! filament severing if



!---------------- capping ------------------

    pl=ph
    ph=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta_sev+beta_cp)/alpha0

    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
!   cap=cap-1   Pool conc. remains same
    Bstate = 2
    Rid="CAPPING +"
    endif


!---------------- de-capping ------------------

    pl=ph
    ph=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta_sev+beta_cp+beta_cm)/alpha0

    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
!   cap=cap+1   Pool conc. remains same
    Bstate = 1
    Rid="CAPPING -"
    endif



!---------- hydrolysis in filament -----------

    pl=(beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta_sev+beta_cp+beta_cm)/alpha0

    do j=l1pind0,l1bind0                    

    if(m10(j).eq.1)then                 
    ph=pl+(ktdpi/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(j) = 2
    Rid="HYD atp"
    endif
    pl=ph

    elseif(m10(j).eq.2)then                 

    if(m10(j-1).eq.4.or.m10(j+1).eq.4)then          
    pifactr=alpha
    else
    pifactr=1.d0
    endif
    ph=pl+(pifactr*ktd/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(j) = 3
    Rid="Pi Release"
    endif
    pl=ph

    elseif(m10(j).eq.3)then                 
    domflag=0
    if(ndom.gt.0)then   ! ndom-if
    do k=1,ndom
    if(j.eq.domL(k)) then
    domflag=1
    endif
    if(j.eq.domR(k)) then
    domflag=1
    endif
    enddo
    endif       ! ndom-if

    if (domflag.lt.1) then
    ph=pl+((kpdom*mcf/V)/alpha0)                
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(j) = 4
!   mcf=mcf-1   Pool conc. remains same
    ndom=ndom+1
    domL(ndom)=j-1
    domR(ndom)=j+1   
    Rid="DOM"
    endif
    pl=ph
    endif

    endif   ! hydrolysis if

    enddo       ! j monomer loop

                                
    if(ndom.gt.0)then       ! ndom if           

    do k=1,ndom

    dumdl=domR(k)-domL(k)-1                 

    !--------------------- domain growth --------------------
    if (m10(domL(k)).eq.3) then     ! Left boundary ADP-if
    ph=pl+((kpcf*mcf/V)/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(domL(k))=4
!   mcf=mcf-1       Pool conc. remains same
    domL(k)=domL(k)-1
    Rid="DOML+"
    endif
    pl=ph
    endif

    if (m10(domR(k)).eq.3) then     ! Right boundary ADP-if
    ph=pl+((kpcf*mcf/V)/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(domR(k))=4
!   mcf=mcf-1       Pool conc. remains same
    domR(k)=domR(k)+1
    Rid="DOMR+"
    endif
    pl=ph
    endif

!   --------------------- domain shrinkage -------------------
    if (m10(domL(k)).le.3.and.dumdl.gt.2) then  
    ph=pl+(kmcf/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(domL(k)+1)=3
!   mcf=mcf+1       Pool conc. remains same
    domL(k)=domL(k)+1
    Rid="DOML-"
    endif
    pl=ph
    endif

    if (m10(domR(k)).le.3.and.dumdl.gt.2) then  
    ph=pl+(kmcf/alpha0)
    if (r2.ge.pl.and.r2.lt.ph) then
    m1(domR(k)-1)=3
!   mcf=mcf+1       Pool conc. remains same
    domR(k)=domR(k)-1
    Rid="DOMR-"
    endif
    pl=ph
    endif


    
    enddo       ! k ndom loop   
    endif       ! ndom if
    

!----------------- count bound cofilin --------------------

    cofcount=0
    do j=l1pind,l1bind
    if (m1(j).eq.4) then
    cofcount=cofcount+1
    endif
    enddo

!------------------- ERROR CHECKS ----------------------

    if (tau.lt.0.d0) exit tloop
    if (m1(l1bind).ne.0.or.m1(l1pind).ne.0) exit tloop
    if (m.ne.N) exit tloop
    if (mcf.ne.Ncf) exit tloop
    if (cap.ne.Ncp) exit tloop

    t = t + tau


    enddo tloop     !***** time loop *****

!------------------ time loop ended -----------------------



    write(*,*) 'domains created', ndom
    do k=1,ndom
    write(*,*) k, 'size', domR(k)-domL(k)-1, 'L-R', domL(k), domR(k)
    enddo

    do k=l1pind,l1bind
    write(101,*) k, m1(k)
    enddo

    if(t.ge.time) write(*,*) 'CODE ENDED WITHOUT ERROR'
    write(*,*) 'CODE STOPPED ','t=',t,'id=',Rid

    if (tau.lt.0.d0) write(*,*) 'ERROR: tau negative', tau, alpha0, beta1+beta2+beta3+beta4+beta5, beta6, beta7
    if (m1(l1bind).ne.0.or.m1(l1pind).ne.0) write(*,*) 'ERROR: l1bind/l1pind not zero', m1(l1bind), m1(l1pind)
    if (m.ne.N) write(*,*) 'ERROR: constant conc. fails', m, N 
    if (mcf.ne.Ncf) write(*,*) 'ERROR: constant conc. fails', mcf, Ncf
    if (cap.ne.Ncp) write(*,*) 'ERROR: constant conc. fails', cap, Ncp

    write(*,*) 'pe',l1pind,'be',l1bind, 'domains', ndom


    stop
    end program code
```

O/P when W1 and W2 are commented out:

```
 Array size=        -100       22200
 domains created          30
           1 size          40 L-R           0          41
           2 size           0 L-R          -1           0
           3 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           4 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           5 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           6 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           7 size         113 L-R          40         154
           8 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           9 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          10 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          11 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          12 size          57 L-R         153         211
          13 size         -40 L-R         250         211
          14 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          15 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          16 size         -11 L-R         378         368
          17 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          18 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          19 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          20 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          21 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          22 size         -16 L-R         499         484
          23 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          24 size          -8 L-R         545         538
          25 size          -5 L-R         581         577
          26 size         -11 L-R         516         506
          27 size         -41 L-R         617         577
          28 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          29 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          30 size          -1 L-R         703         703
 CODE ENDED WITHOUT ERROR
 CODE STOPPED t=   3600.9739030733977      id=BE+                                                                             
 pe          -1 be         239 domains          30
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
```

O/P when W1 is NOT commented out:

```
 Array size=        -100       22200
 sever           4         144         550           2           1
 sever           2         108         239           2           1
 sever           2         207         475           1           1
 sever           2         256         407           2           2
 sever           2         224         579           2           2
 sever           4         226         297           1           1
 sever           2         337         562           2           2
 sever           3         324         476           1           1
 sever           4         376         611           1           1
 sever           4         369         436           1           0
 sever           4         615         943           1           1
 sever           3         582         776           1           2
 sever           4         409         734           1           1
 sever           2         364         403           1           1
 sever           4         512         833           3           2
 sever           3         463         568           2           2
 sever           4         450         493           1           1
 sever           2         430         446           0           1
 sever           3         865        1299           4           4
 sever           4         812        1041           3           3
 sever           4         547         813           1           1
 sever           2         545         851           2           1
 sever           2         573         765           1           1
 domains created          31
           1 size         122 L-R           0         123
           2 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           3 size           0 L-R          -1           0
           4 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           5 size          75 L-R         122         198
           6 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           7 size          -1 L-R           0           0
           8 size          39 L-R         197         237
           9 size          48 L-R         236         285
          10 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          11 size           3 L-R         316         320
          12 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          13 size           0 L-R         356         357
          14 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          15 size          36 L-R         319         356
          16 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          17 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          18 size         139 L-R         357         497
          19 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          20 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          21 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          22 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          23 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          24 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          25 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          26 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          27 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          28 size          47 L-R         517         565
          29 size          21 L-R         496         518
          30 size          -1 L-R           0           0
          31 size          -1 L-R           0           0
 CODE ENDED WITHOUT ERROR
 CODE STOPPED t=   3600.0320511744094      id=HYD atp                                                                         
 pe          -1 be         688 domains          31
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
```

None of the results are unphysical and the different results can be reproduced with a different compiler on a mac. I have also compiled with `gfortran -Wall -Wno-tabs -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace gillsp_notworking.f90` but did not find any serious issue. Apart from the different results, the code can sometime freeze as well in some combination of commenting out the two write statements and that seems to depend on what combination I ran before (crazy!) - if this helps in the diagnosis. Any help or hints are welcome. Thank you in advance!
------ EDIT 1 --------
compiling with optimization flag supresses different outputs but freezes in some cases (e.g., when W1,W2 are not commented out):
`gfortran -O gillsp_notworking.f90`
does not solve the problem.
------ EDIT 2 ---------
Following suggestion from comments, I have now compiled with debugging options and bound check options:
`gfortran -Wall -Wno-tabs -Wextra -fbounds-check gillsp_notworking.f90` 
but this just gives me some warning about unused parameters.
Following the suggestion of using `random_number()` I have modified the code in the current version and the subsequent different behaviours too. It freezes if I keep both the write statements. Also if I compile using `-Og` flag (i.e., `gfortran -Og gillsp_notworking_seed.f90`) when both W1,W2 are commented out then the results change!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331608/fortran-runtime-error-fixed-by-writing-output.  There are other Qs and As on similar topics too.

Comment: "Runtime Error: test.f90, line 242: Reference to undefined variable NMERGE. " Once you fix that, you'll get more errors. Basically, the error isn't where you think it is: the program screwed up the stack long before that.

Comment: And the fact that you've got random numbers in there doesn't exactly help repeatability!

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @lastchance nmerge is defined as an integer, "integer :: k1,k2, dgcount, dscount, nmerge, domflag" but I agree there might be other problems is there a way to debug it systematically? any option flags?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks! I was looking at some of them and checked with some flags in compilation. I will check the two points you mentioned and reply soon.

Comment: @Deb S. B. , I used “nagfor -C=undefined test.f90” and picked up that nmerge hadn’t been assigned any value. Unfortunately, since you use random numbers, this may or may not occur. Similar problems occur with beta1 etc. You’ve declared them, but in some cases appear not to have given them a value. Your if-blocks seem to be able to bypass them for some random numbers. Please use the standard random_number(…) rather than rand(), so that we can test with different compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GFortran 11.3 (the default version included in Ubuntu 22.04), compiling with `-Og -Wall` and then fixing the `may be used uninitialized` warnings by setting in the initialization block

```
    beta1 = 0
    beta2 = 0
    beta3 = 0
    beta4 = 0
    beta5 = 0
    beta_cp = 0
    beta_cm = 0
    nmerge = 0
```

I get the same output regardless if those two write statements are commented out or not, and regardless of optimization level (tried `-O0`, `-O2`, `-Og`, `-O3` and `-O3 -ffast-math`). Also neither `-fcheck=all` and `-fsanitize=undefined` nor `-fsanitize=address` finds any problem (which of course isn't a guarantee that problems aren't there, but gives a bit of indication at least).

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem! Thank you so much @janneb! I did not get that warning in my gfortran version. I am not sure if I understand why the error was happening but it may involve some garbage value assigned to uninitiated variables it seems.